# Sharepoint Set-PnpListItem is not updating value of sharepoint list column

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

i have powershell script of PNP for setting list item value using for loop.

$ListItems_Values=(Get-PnPListItem  -List fretag%20vrigt -Fields "FileLeafRef").FieldValues

foreach ($item in $ListItems_Values){
if($item.FileLeafRef -match "Ö")
{
$item.FileLeafRef=$item.FileLeafRef -replace "Ö","O"

Set-PnPListItem -List fretag%20vrigt -Identity $item.FileLeafRef -Values @{"FileLeafRef" = $item.FileLeafRef} -SystemUpdate:$True

Write-Host $item.FileLeafRef "O is replace"
}

else{Write-Host $item.FileLeafRef "O is missing"}
}

it fetching value of FileLeafReaf column but when i set using set_pnplist item it throws below error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

it is solved.Used $item.ID for set item. It only accept Title,ID and GUID column with identity parameter.
foreach ($item in $ListItems_Values){if($item.FileLeafRef -match "Ö"){

$item.FileLeafRefvalue=$item.FileLeafRef -replace "Ö","O"

Set-PnPListItem -List "fretag%20vrigt" -Identity **$item.ID** -Values @{"FileLeafRef" = $item.FileLeafRefvalue} -SystemUpdate:$True
Write-Host $item.FileLeafRefvalue "O is replace"
 }